# How to replace requireJS config in webpack es6 project

Tags: requirejs, webpack, amd

I want to refactor a large requireJS project to use es6 import/export and webpack. In the requireJS `requirejs.config` call, I use the `config` section to pass some project specific settings to some views:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/cfe/app',
  paths: { },
  config: {
    'views/test/TestView': {
      isTest: true
    }
})
```

and in the view:

```
define(['module'], function(module) {
  var t = module.config().isTest
})
```

How can I accomplish the same behaviour in my webpack setup?

Comment: Have you configured webpack to compile your files using babel?

Comment: Yes, that the plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but maybe you can use my answer anyways.

I think you could extract your configuration object to JSON file, use a loader (RAW loader works fine) to include it in your bundle, and then when you need it simply use ES6 import:

```
import config from 'myconfig.json';
```